# Using LINQ in my Business Logic, but getting an error

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The idea is that a Reference Number or Vendor can be passed to the logic and it spits back the query results for the search. I know i'm missing something.. Just can't see it..

The SQL query idea was as follows..

```
 "SELECT ReferenceNumber, VendorName, RequisitionStatus, RequestedOn, sum(RequisitionQTY*RequisitionPrice) as Total FROM partrequisition where ReferenceNumber = 105543 Group By 'ReferenceNumber' "
```

Can anyone help?

I'm getting the following error:

> CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal?>` to
>   `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PartsManagement.Models.partrequisition>`

```
(contoller)
public ActionResult Index(RequisitionSearch searchModel)
{
      var PartRequisitionInfoLogic = new PartRequisitionInfoLogic(); //This is where any business Logic goes
      var Model = PartRequisitionInfoLogic.Getpartrequisitions(searchModel); //This is where it figures out what Search Query is
      var RequisisionResults = Model.ToList();
}
```

```
(Business Logic)
private wsdpartsmanagementEntities9 db = new wsdpartsmanagementEntities9();

public IQueryable<partrequisition> Getpartrequisitions(RequisitionSearch searchModel)
{

    var result = db.partrequisitions.AsQueryable();

    if (searchModel != null)
    {

        if (searchModel.ReferenceNumber != 0 && searchModel.VendorID == 0)

            result = result.Where(c => c.ReferenceNumber == searchModel.ReferenceNumber).GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
                        .Select(g => g.Sum(item => item.RequisitionQTY * item.RequisitionPrice)) // For each group, calculate the sum
                        .ToList();

            if (searchModel.ReferenceNumber == 0 && searchModel.VendorID != 0)

                result = result.Where(c => c.VendorName == searchModel.VendorID).GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
                        .Select(g => g.Sum(item => item.RequisitionQTY * item.RequisitionPrice))// For each group, calculate the sum
                        .ToList();
        }


        return result;
}
```

```
(ViewModel(s))
    public class RequisitionSearch
    {
        public int? VendorID { get; set; }
        public int? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public List<RequisitionResults> SearchResults { get; set; }

        public RequisitionSearch()
        {
            this.SearchResults = new List<RequisitionResults>();
        }
    }
}

public class RequisitionResults
    {
        public int ReferenceID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Reference Number")]
        public int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Vendor Name")]
        public string VendorName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Requisition Status")]
        public string RequisitionStatus { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Requisition On")]
        public DateTime RequestedOn { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        [Display(Name = "Requisition Total")]
        public decimal RequisitionTotal { get; set; }

    }
```

Update.. The solution was to scrap the Business logic and replace it with (below) in the ActionResult. Works perfectly.

```
var result = db.partrequisitions.AsQueryable();
if (searchModel.ReferenceNumber != null || searchModel.VendorID != null)
 {
   result = result.Where(partrequisition => partrequisition.ReferenceNumber == searchModel.ReferenceNumber || partrequisition.VendorName == searchModel.VendorID);
 }
 else
 {
    result = result.Distinct();
 }            

 var b = result.GroupBy(x => x.ReferenceNumber);
 var c = b.Select(group => group.Sum(partRequistion => partRequistion.RequisitionQTY * partRequistion.RequisitionPrice));
```

And to access the query information, a couple of foreach loops..

Comment: which line gives you the error?

Comment: It was the result = result.Where..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had split your big query into smaller ones, and used the keyword var a lot less, then you would have seen your problem at compile time:

Alas you forgot to describe your class `PartRequisition`. From your code it looks similar to:

```
class PartRequisition
{
    public int ReferenceId {get; set;}
    public int ReferenceNumber {get; set;}

    public decimal? RequisitionQty {get; set;}
    public decimal? RequisitionPrice {get; set;}
    // one of them might be not a decimal? but a decimal.
}
```

Your code:

```
IQueryable<PartRequisition> result = db.partrequisitions.AsQueryable();
result = result
    .Where(partRequistion => partRequisition.ReferenceID == searchModel.ReferenceNumber)
    .GroupBy(partRequistion => partRequistion.ReferenceNumber)
    .Select(group => group.Sum(partRequistion =>
            partRequistion.RequisitionQTY * partRequistion.RequisitionPrice))
    .ToList();
```

Let's split this into smaller parts:

```
IQueryable<PartRequisition> result = ...
IQueryable<PartRequisition> a =  result.Where(partRequistion => ... == ...);
IQueryable<IGrouping<int, PartRequisition>> b = a.GroupBy(
                          partRequistion => partRequistion.ReferenceNumber);
```

So b is a queryable sequence of groups. Every group has an integer property Key. Each group is also a sequence of `PartRequistions`, namely all `PartRequisitions` that have a value of `ReferenceNumber` equal to the Key.

In the Select, you take each group of your sequence of groups. From every element in this group (which is a `PartRequisition`) you multiply two `decimal?` properties, which gives us a `decimal?` result. After that you sum these results, using `Sum<decimal?>`

```
IQueryable<decimal?> c = b.Select(group => group.Sum(partRequistion =>
    partRequistion.RequisitionQTY * partRequistion.RequisitionPrice)
```

Or in even smaller steps:

- c is IQueryable>`
- Every group is `IGrouping<int, PartRequisition>`
- every partRequisition is a `PartRequisition`
- every RequisitionQTY and RequisitionPrice are decimial?
- the result of the multiplication is `decimal?`
- the result of the Sum is `decimal?`
- d is IQueryable

Finally:

```
List<decimal?> d = c.ToList();
result = d;  // remember, result is an IQueryable<PartRequisition>
```

It is clear to see that you can't assign a `List<decimal?>` to an `IQueryable<PartRequisition>`, which was exactly what the error said:

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type List to DbSet

**Back to your problem**

You descirbed a class `RequistionResult` that you didn't use in method `GetRequisitions`.
Can it be that you don't want to return an `IQueryable<PartRequistions>`
but an `IQueryable<RequisitionResult>`,
where property `RequisitionTotal` is your calculated Sum?

```
public IQueryable<RequisitionResult> GetRequisitions(...)
{
    IQueryable<PartRequisition> partRequisitions = db.partrequisitions.AsQueryable();

    if (searchModel != null)
    {
        if (searchModel.ReferenceNumber != 0 && searchModel.VendorID == 0)
        {
            partRequisitions = partRequisitions.Where(...);
        }
        else if (searchModel.ReferenceNumber == 0 && searchModel.VendorID != 0)
        {
            partRequisitions = partRequisitions.Where(...);
        }
        // else use all PartRequisitions
    }
    else
    {
         // TODO: decide what to return if searchModel is null, for example
         partRequisitions = IQueryable.Empty<PartRequisition>();
         // or use all PartRequisitions
    }

    // from the remaining set of PartRequisitions, convert to RequisitionResults:
    IQueryable<RequisitionResult> requisitionResults = partRequisitions
        .GroupBy(partRequisition => partRequisition.ReferenceNumber,

        // parameter ResultSelector: take each ReferenceNumber and all PartRequisitions
        // with this ReferenceNumber to make one new RequisitionResult
        (referenceNumber, partRequisitionsWithThisReferenceNumber) => new RequisitionResult
        {
            RequisitionTotal = partRequisitionsWithThisReferenceNumber
               .Select(partRequisition => partRequisition.RequisitionQty * partRequisition.RequisitionPrice)
               .Sum(),

            // fill other properties
            ...
        });
    return requisitionResults;
}
```

Comment: I like your idea of breaking it into smaller queries..  The line:  IQueryable<IGrouping<int, partrequisition>> b = a.GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber); Causes an error message CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int?, PartsManagement.Models.partrequisition>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, PartsManagement.Models.partrequisition>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You do know the difference between `int?` and `int`, don't you? If not, spend some time discovering what nullable types are and how you use them. I don't know your classes. Are the properties decimal or nullable decimal? If it can't automatically convert the nullable to the non-nullable, you should convert it explicitly. If there is an error in my answer, feel free to edit it after your investigations

Comment: I ended up breaking the Linq query in to 3 smaller queries.  Thank you for the idea..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following line carefully:

```
 result = result.Where(c => c.VendorName == searchModel.VendorID)
                .GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
                .Select(g => g.Sum(item => item.RequisitionQTY * item.RequisitionPrice))// For each group, calculate the sum
                .ToList();
```

You are trying to return a `List` Of `Decimal?` values using the `Sum` method while your method's return type is `IQueryable<partrequisition>`. So what you need is either changing your method's return type to a `List` of `Decimals?` or change your query in order to fulfill what your method actually needs by returning an `IQueryable` of `partrequisition`.

Comment: How would you write it? Everything works until I try and incorporate the calculation.

Comment: @user474848 Can you show what is your mean by updating your question?

Comment: When I started out with  result = result.Where(c => c.ReferenceNumber == searchModel.ReferenceNumber). It gave me the base information about the partrequisition from the database.. Then I thought why couldn't the query also do the total cost of the requisition as well. That is when things started to go south..  The concept was "SELECT ReferenceNumber, VendorName, RequisitionStatus, RequestedOn, sum(RequisitionQTY*RequisitionPrice) as Total FROM partrequisition where ReferenceNumber = 105543 Group By 'ReferenceNumber' "

Comment: @user474848 It seems you need to return anonymous-types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: @user474848 I can't see anything wrong with your query, but with your method return type and the LINQ query result. You need either change your method's return type or change the query result.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. How you would write this?